# Exit command without confirmation in python

Tags: python, python-idle

In Python if the `exit()` command is raised, it will confirm before exiting. I do not like the idea of clicking the exit button every time. Is there a way to bypass this confirmation? (This is using the IDLE shell)

Comment: I've never seen that behavior. Are you using a special interpreter, environment, or IDE?

Comment: This is surely a duplicate.

Comment: @Tigerhawk13, I am using the python 2.7.11 shell

Comment: And what environment or wrapper is accessing that 2.7.11 shell? You certainly aren't using a standard terminal emulator like cmd or Konsole. The standard interactive interpreter doesn't produce a friendly little "Really exit? (Yes) (No)" dialog box with buttons to click after you `exit()`.

Comment: Are you using IDLE?

Comment: That is the environment/IDE that was causing this behavior, and which you should've mentioned without forcing others to guess.

Comment: In addition to ^D, File - Close,  Alt-F4 (current window) and File - Exit, ^Q (all windows) all exit immediately in the shell.  Both ask about saving unsaved data in an Editor window.  There have been requests to have the box also pop up if there is unsaved data in the shell.  Some people routinely save their shell sessions.  It is hard to please everyone ;-).  The "kill running process" message appears in other circumstances.  I don't know what the C-coded quit/exit functions are doing to prompt that particular message.  In any case, hit <Enter> twice instead of once.

Comment: File-Close (window) is same as the windows [X] button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + d is the shortcut for exiting the python interpreter. This works for IDLE and an interactive Python shell (linux, windows or osx). In an IPython shell you will be asked for [y/n] confirmation to exit.

Comment: You might want to mention that _this is for IDLE only_.

Comment: ^D is a standard END of FILE exit control code on unix.  see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell.   IDLE imitates that and being a cross platform app, acts the same on all platforms.  ^Z used to be the same on Windows and when it was, IDLE recognized *that*.